# Список страниц WP Plugin

Tags: wordpress, плагин

Создание плагинов под wordpress для меня дело новое. На данный момент стоит задача вывести на странице настройки плагина, список созданных страниц и затем записать в выбранные определенную информацию.
Собственно, нужен вывод и записать, любая помощь пригодиться.

Comment: @Undefitied, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Советую по данному вопросу обратиться к [кодексу](http://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8), в нем написано, как создать страницу настроек плагина, как делать поля настроек и как их сохранять.